# How to Convert a JSON Object to JSON Array using GSON in Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

Hi I am new to Kotlin and Android I want to parse an `JSONObject` and Convert it into Array ,
Here is my sample JSON looks like

```
{
        "USDAED": 3.672982,
        "USDAFN": 57.8936,
        "USDALL": 126.1652,
        "USDAMD": 475.306,
        "USDANG": 1.78952,
        "USDAOA": 109.216875,
        "USDARS": 8.901966,
        "USDAUD": 1.269072,
        "USDAWG": 1.792375,
        "USDAZN": 1.04945,
        "USDBAM": 1.757305}
```

I want to store JSONObject in a HashMap .Or How to Iterate over the JSON Object keys in Kotlin.

I am using GSON.

Please don't vote if its easy please provide the link.

Comment: You may try like this `val jsonObject = JSONObject("your json string")
    val keys: Iterator<String> = jsonObject.keys()
    val map: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        val key = keys.next()
        val value = jsonObject.getString(key)
        map[key] = value
    }`

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do it by simply use Split object value as like below
`jsonObject.toString().split(",")` its return list of String.
if you want to iterate each value then you can use like below code

```
  val jsonArray = jsonObject.toString().split(",")
    for (element in jsonArray){
        Log.i(TAG, "doSomeWork: $element")
    }
```

and also can convert to list as like :- `jsonArray.toList()`

Hope its help you

Comment: It won't work if json has only one element `{"USDAED": 3.672982`}